# win10 pycharm terminal bug: display confusion

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

Please forgive my poor English.

I'm using win10 system, pycharm version is profession--2017.3.3, and the pycharm.exe is verified by SHA256.

When I open terminal, it seemed ok,
[image: Terminal Image #1]

but when I entering '1' in the terminal, it becomes confused.

[image: Terminal Image #2]

Keep entering '1', it becomes more confused.

[image: Terminal Image #3]

Then, I enter 'ENTER' directly,

[image: Terminal Image #4]

keep entering 'ENTER', it seemes normal.

[image: Terminal Image #5]

But when I enter a string like '1', it still can't run normally.

[image: Terminal Image #6]

Comment: I'm sorry that the image is not display directly, and I don't have permission to edit my question. T T

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by creating new user in win10 system.
By the way, before creating new user, the problem still exist even if I 
reinstall the system.